# C# Calculator using List Array error at some operations Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, calculator

Hello I'm still new to programming and yes this is not the best code you will see... I tried making calculator on C# windows form for fun and I'm having trouble on the subtraction and division operations, but the addition and multiplication works perfectly fine for me. I decided to have a list array so that I would be able to input numbers as much as I want.

The error for the subtraction is when I input for example 5 - 2 the result will be -3

As for the division the error is that the result is always 1

Please tell me where did I go wrong and give a detailed explanation if possible so that I would understand more about programming. Thanks in advance!

```
namespace CalculatorTestForm1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static List<int> Numlist = new List<int>();
    public static string operation;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Num = (Button)sender;
        TXTBox.Text += Num.Text;
    }

    private void BPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operation = "add";
        int AddNum = Convert.ToInt32(this.TXTBox.Text);
        Numlist.Add(AddNum);
        TXTBox.Text = "";          
    }

    private void BEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        int AddNum = Convert.ToInt32(this.TXTBox.Text);
        Numlist.Add(AddNum);

        int sum = 0;
        int product = 1;
        int quotient = 1;
        int difference = 0;

        if (operation == "add"){
            foreach (int value in Numlist)
            {
                sum += value;
            }
            string Answer = sum.ToString();
            TXTBox.Text = Answer;    
        }else if(operation == "minus"){
            foreach (int value in Numlist)
            {
                difference = value - difference;
            }
            string Answer = difference.ToString();
            TXTBox.Text = Answer;
        }
        else if (operation == "multiply")
        {
            foreach (int value in Numlist)
            {
                product *= value;
            }
            string Answer = product.ToString();
            TXTBox.Text = Answer;
        }
        else if (operation == "divide")
        {
            foreach (int value in Numlist)
            {
                quotient = value / value;
            }
            string Answer = quotient.ToString();
            TXTBox.Text = Answer;
        }
        Numlist.Clear();
    }

    private void BClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TXTBox.Text = "";
        Numlist.Clear();
    }

    private void BMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operation = "minus";
        int AddNum = Convert.ToInt32(this.TXTBox.Text);
        Numlist.Add(AddNum);
        TXTBox.Text = "";         
    }

    private void BDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operation = "divide";
        int AddNum = Convert.ToInt32(this.TXTBox.Text);
        Numlist.Add(AddNum);
        TXTBox.Text = "";  
    }

    private void BMulti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operation = "multiply";
        int AddNum = Convert.ToInt32(this.TXTBox.Text);
        Numlist.Add(AddNum);
        TXTBox.Text = "";         
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with division is obvious from reading the source code: `quotient = value / value;`

Answer (score 2):

For the division it's obvious:

```
quotient = value / value;
```

`value`/`value` will always be `1`.

There must be `quotient` in that loop somewhere...

For the subtraction the problem is that because of the way you do it, the order of the numbers are reversed.

lets say 5 - 2:

```
foreach (int value in Numlist)
{
    difference = value - difference;
}
```

`NumList = {5,2}`

1st iteration:
`difference = value(5) - difference(0) = 5`

2nd iteration:
`difference = value(2) - difference(5) = -3`

You should reverse the order of the loop: `NumList.Reverse()`

And for the division as well:

*Division:*

```
foreach (int value in Numlist.Reverse())
{
    quotient = value / quotient;
}
```

*Subtraction:*

```
foreach (int value in Numlist)
{
    difference = value - difference;
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so much! I never knew that you could actually do Numlist.Reverse() in code. Thanks a lot again, never expect that there would be a great community in programming.